# solr query exactly similar to mysql like

Tags: mysql, solr

Hello i am having trouble to exactly replicate mysql like functionality with solr 
Following is my testcase scenario

when i search for "ryan decosta" in solr with `q=xyz:*ryan decosta*` solr will return document where xyz having "ryan decosta","ryan","decosta","dasdecosta","ryaneqwddd","efdefsryan decostadsadsad","ryan decostadsadsad","efdefsryan decosta" etc

when i search for "ryan decosta" in mysql with `like xyz="%ryan decosta%"` mysql will return rows where  xyz having "ryan decosta","efdefsryan decostadsadsad","ryan decostadsadsad","efdefsryan decosta" but it will not return "ryan","decosta" separately

i don't want "ryan","decosta" separately in my search

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried `q=xyz:*"ryan decosta"*`?

Comment: It doesn't work. Returing a vast no of extra result

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly? Results containing the sequence including space with prefix or postfix? Or results with both words in any order? How is the configuration of the field? Do you use analyzers in indexing/querying? Easiest to show the respective part of your schema.xml

Comment: i want Results containing the sequence including space with prefix and postfix. here is the schema <field name="xyz" type="text_general" stored="true" />

Comment: What is text_general? Don't explain, just put the snippet into your question...

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here:
[How to get same result as following Mysql query from Solr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28138583/how-to-get-same-result-as-following-mysql-query-from-solr/28247726#28247726)

Mysql *computes* the unanchored string match by touching every row.  Solr (and any index technology) is designed to **avoid** touching every record at query-time.  It supports **anchored** text matching with `EdgeNGramFilterFactory`.